# Casting generic return type to interface type

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a factory method for a generic Wrapper and I have the problem that I either need to pass in the desired return type (wrapTyped()-method) or I have to explicitly cast an input argument to the desired return type (wrapAuto()-method, 1st use). But I am *lazy* and don't want to write the extra cast :)

Is there any way to express the declaration of wrapAuto() so that case "wantThis" (at the very bottom) works?

```
public class GenericFactory {

static class Wrapper<T> {
    T wrappdObject;
    boolean flag;
    String name;

    public Wrapper(T wrappedObject, boolean flag, String name) {
        this.wrappdObject = wrappedObject;
        this.flag = flag;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public T getObject() {
        return wrappdObject;
    }

    // some more irrelevant methods
}

static interface InterfaceType {
}

static class ImplementationA implements InterfaceType {
}

static <U> Wrapper<U> wrapTyped(Class<U> type, U wrappedObject, boolean flag, String name) { 
    return new Wrapper<U>(wrappedObject, flag, name);
}

static <U> Wrapper<U> wrapAuto(U wrappedObject, boolean flag, String name) {
    return new Wrapper<U>(wrappedObject, flag, "NoName");
}

// compiles, but is cumbersome
public Wrapper<InterfaceType> cumbersome = wrapTyped(InterfaceType.class, new ImplementationA(), true, "A");

// compiles, but is also cumbersome
public Wrapper<InterfaceType> alsoUgly = wrapAuto((InterfaceType) new ImplementationA(), true, "B");

// Want this, but "Type mismatch error"
public Wrapper<InterfaceType> wantThis = wrapAuto(new ImplementationA(), false, "C");

}
```

I stripped it down a little, for simplicity I declared only one set of interface and concrete implementation. I practice the class Wrapper may be used for many completely different, unrelated types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method `wrapAuto`, add another type parameter, with `U` as upper bound, and use it as the formal parameter type:

```
static <U, T extends U> Wrapper<U> wrapAuto(T wrappedObject, boolean flag, String name) {
    return new Wrapper<U>(wrappedObject, flag, "NoName");
}
```

and then this would work:

```
Wrapper<InterfaceType> wantThis = wrapAuto(new ImplementationA(), false, "C");
```

With this invocation, `T` is inferred as `ImplementationA`, and `U` is inferred as `InterfaceType`. And the bounds `T extends U` perfectly matches these types.

---

**References:**

- [Java Generics FAQs - Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [What is a type parameter bound?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#What%20is%20a%20type%20parameter%20bound?)
  - [Can I use a type parameter as a type parameter bound?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Can%20I%20use%20a%20type%20parameter%20as%20a%20type%20parameter%20bound?)

Comment: Wow, beautiful and simple. Even Wrapper<Number> n = wrapAuto(7, ...); works like a charm now.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the signature of the method to start with. This is an inference problem. I don't think adding extra unnecessary type parameters to the method is a good way do deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your method as written. But inference is not perfect. You can always explicitly specify the type arguments:

```
public Wrapper<InterfaceType> wantThis = GenericFactory.<InterfaceType>wrapAuto(new ImplementationA(), false, "C");
```